# upgrade activescaffold (deprecated functions) in rails 2.3 to 3.0 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activescaffold, rails-3-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade an app **from rails 2.3 to 3.0** and it uses Active-scaffold plug-in

In the upgrade process I've removed Active-scaffold (rails 2.3 compatible plug-in) and installed gem active_scaffold-3.0.26

But I often get the following errors

```
Error message:
    undefined method `ui_type=' for #<ActiveScaffold::DataStructures::Column:0xfdf57f0>
Exception class:
    NoMethodError
```

and

```
Error message:
    undefined method `live_search=' for #<ActiveScaffold::DataStructures::Column:0xfdf57f0>
Exception class:
    NoMethodError
```

Seems the functions `ui_type, live_search` are deprecated in the new version but I couldn't find any proper documentation about the **alternatives for deprecated functions**

Or any **information about upgrading ActiveScaffold plugin in rails 3**